# Rewrite a function in PHP for exploding an array in which doesn't give me this error:

Tags: php, arrays, forms, cookies

> Error:
>       Notice: Undefined index: volunteerServicesForm in C:\xampp\htdocs\vgh\volunteer-new\index.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\vgh\volunteer-new\index.php on line 7
>       Skip to Content

//CODE BELOW THAT GAVE ME THE ERROR:

```
    <?php

    function explode_with_key($str, $inglue = "~", $outglue = '^')  {
        $hash = array();
        foreach (explode($outglue, $str) as $pair) {           
            $k2v = explode($inglue, $pair);   
 line 7         $hash[$k2v[0]] = $k2v[1];
        }
        return $hash;
    }
 line 13    $cookies = explode_with_key($_COOKIE['volunteerServicesForm']);
    ?>
```

I just want a quick solution, because I've been working too long on this whole form (that was coded by someone else) and I don't know enough to fix this one part. I will appreciate your explanation so I can put it in comments and understand it next time. For now, I just want help to get rid of the error. Please?

All I really know is that the form stores the field values in cookies, which are key values, and I think the coder did this because of the limit of cookies on some browsers. I don't agree with the solution but it's what I have to work with. I know that sessions might be better for security and probably easier than this. But please help me fix this so I can move on, as well as send you great thanks and appreciation and good reviews. Normally I take out that time to really study this and learn it myself, so please don't judge me. It's really a time issue and I apologize for being so lame.

Comment: Without looking at the function, it looks like your problem is that the key doesn't exist. You should check if it exists first. Something like `if (!empty($_COOKIE['volunteerServicesForm'])) { $cookies = explode_with_key($_COOKIE['volunteerServicesForm']); }`

Comment: Dump $k2v after you explode it to make sure it is a 2 part array and that it's what you think it is.

Comment: Please mention the line number so that other can understand the error line number.

Comment: That makes sense Andrew. I'll try that first.

Comment: It looks like my question was answered, where can I mention that it was solved?

Comment: If Andrew's comment was the answer, he should post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: It was. In fact, I knew it as soon as I saw it because that was what was wrong with most of the code on the whole form. As for making a 2 part array, I'm not sure if that was the solution to this particular problem or not. The error was gone from Andrews answer, but I don't know if the 2 part array would be more proper. Anyway, I'll research that further. Thanks all of you I appreciate all your help! and please resolve this with Andrews answer. If I try the 2 part array, I will have to post somewhere else about it.